# React Router (v4) works for page reloads, but does not trigger UI event via <Link/>s

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-redux

React Router has been working fine during development with my Webpack dev server and hot reloader, but when configuring for production it seems to fail. It works when the page is refreshed, but `<Link/>` components and pushing to the History API are not causing the UI to change. My setup is as follows. Where `render` is the setup that works locally with Webpack dev server and `renderTest` is what isn't working.

```
const render = Component => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={Theme}>
      <Router>
        <AppContainer>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Component/>
            </Provider>
        </AppContainer>
      </Router>
    </MuiThemeProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
};

const renderTest = Component => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={Theme}>
      <Router>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Component/>
        </Provider>
      </Router>
    </MuiThemeProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
};

//render(Root);
renderTest(Root);

// if (module.hot) {
//   module.hot.accept('./containers/root-container/root-container', () => { render(Root) });
// }
```

Comment: "it seems to fail" is not sufficient information, can you provide the exact error you are experiencing?

Comment: sure, clicking a <Link/> does not cause the UI to change. but manually going to a route (e.g. htttp://localhost:8080/some/route) works.

Comment: ok I figured it out. turns out there is a known compatibility issue with react router (v4) and redux. (more info on that here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4671) a work around that I found to work for my situation was to wrap my root component with `withRouter` that way the location context gets passed to every component. Not an ideal solution, but it works until there is an official fix.

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer below and mark it as the answer so others can more clearly see your solution

Comment: thanks, I'm new to not just lurking stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

ok I figured it out. turns out there is a known compatibility issue with react router (v4) and redux. (more info on that here: github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4671) a work around that I found to work for my situation was to wrap my root component with withRouter that way the location context gets passed to every component. Not an ideal solution, but it works until there is an official fix.

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Root));
```